# Button on submenu in nav

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, nav

I want to add dropdown to my current nav bar. I tried this code but dropdown content disappeared and now I don´t have any ideas to edit code to this be working. After my last edit it´s only show dropdown menu but I don´t click on any link. Dropdown, dropbtn was added to previous code. Can you help me with this? Thanks very much!

Here is code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="menu.png" />
<title>MENU | Úvodné menu</title>
<meta charset=utf-8>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<style>
body {
  height: 100%;
  
  background-image: linear-gradient(orange, red);
}
</style>
<style>
body,h1 {font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif}
body, html {height: 100%}
.bgimg {
  background-image: linear-gradient(orange, red);
  min-height: 100%;
  background-position: full;
  background-size: ;
}
</style>
<style>
* {box-sizing: border-box;}

body { 
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
  font-size: 16px;  
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  margin: 0;
}



.header {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: orange;
  padding: 20px 10px;
}

.header a {
  float: left;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px; 
  line-height: 25px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.header a.logo {
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.header a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

.header a.active {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}

.header-right {
  float: right;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  .header a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
  
  .header-right {
    float: none;
  }
}


.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}
.dropdown {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
.dropbtn:hover ~ .dropdown-content {display: block;}
</style>
</head>
<body onload="startTime()">

<div class="header">
 <a id="txt" hidden></a>
<img src="https://i.ibb.co/6Nkbdb3/dlhemenu-1-1-1.png" class="logo" title="Odhlásiť sa" alt="MENU logo" width="150" height="50" onclick="window.location='/logout.php'"> 
 &nbsp
 <a class="dropbtn"><i class="fa fa-user">&nbsp</i>Dropdown 
      <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
    </a>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>   


    <div class="header-right">
    <a class="active" href="/welcome.php">Úvodné menu</a>
        <a href="/online.html">Online hodiny</a>
    <a href="/vyplnit.html">Testy na vyplnenie</a>
    <a href="/znamky3.html">Známky</a>
    <a href="/rozvrh.html">Rozvrh hodín</a>
     <a href="/dochadzka.html">Dochádzka</a>
      <a href="/ucenie.html">Učebný materiál</a>
       <a href="/hry.html">Hry</a>
  <a href="/omne.php">O mne</a>
  
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: There are so many wrong things with this code that I don't even know where to start. My suggestion: before attempting to do things with JS learn the basics with HTML and CSS. Also, take the time to build a good HTML structure.

Comment: Thanks for advice. I need do this can you help me?

Comment: Snippet is alredy created

Comment: Let me know if the answer of @ELTi-42 helped. If not I could try help you out, maybe in a few hours or tomorrow.

Comment: His answer is not working. Thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this case I would suggest using **Bootstrap**, it will make life easier for you. It mainly allows people to apply some nice functionalities without leaving their HTML.

[Here is the link](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/components/navbar/) to the docs of bootstrap v4.6 navbars. And [here you can find all the docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/getting-started/introduction/).

You could try to integrate something as bellow in your website:

```html
<html>
  <head>
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.5.1/dist/jquery.slim.min.js" defer></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" defer></script>
    <title>MENU | Úvodné menu</title>
    <meta charset=utf-8>
  </head>
  
  <body>
    <!-- Start of navbar -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-dark" style="background:#FFBD35">

      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">

          <!-- Section_1 link -->
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Úvodné Menu<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
          </li>

          <!-- Section_2 link -->
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Online hodiny</a>
          </li>

          <!-- Section_3 link -->
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Testy na vyplnenie</a>
          </li>

           <!-- Dropdown -->
          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
               <i class="fa fa-user"></i>&nbsp; Dropdown
            </a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
            </div>
          </li>

        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <!-- End of navbar -->
  
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks! That was helpfuly for me.

Comment: Cool that helped. Bootstrap will help you a lot, but take the time to study and play with it. Don't rush, it takes time and effort to learn it. But it will be the best path for you in my opinion.

Comment: I appreciate your advice. And thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

if i understand your question correctly you are searching for a simple dropdown menu with js?

here is a short excample

HTML:

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- your header settings -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="page.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <span id="dropbtn">
        <span class="fa fa-user"></span>
        <span>Dropdown</span>
        <span class="fa fa-caret-down"></span>
      </span>
      <div id="dropdown-content" class="hidden">
        <a href="#">Link 1</a>
        <a href="#">Link 2</a>
        <a href="#">Link 3</a>
      </div>  
    </header>

    <script src="menu.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

First in this excample HTML, CSS and JS in seperated Files. Than you get a better overview and your code perhaps will be reuseable in future ;)

CSS:

```
.hidden {
  display:none;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
function clickListener_btn(event){
  /** @type {HTMLElement} */
  let clickedElement = event.currentTarget();

  /** @type {HTMLElement} */
  let dropDownMenu = document.querySelector('#dropdown-content');
  if(dropDownMenu.classList.has('hidden') {
    dropDownMenu.classList.remove('hidden');
  } else {
    dropDownMenu.classList.add('hidden');
  }
}

/** @type {HTMLElement} */
let btn = document.querySelector('#dropbtn');

btn.addEventListener('click', clickListener_btn);
```

Problem No. 1 with your code. You click on a `<a>` Tag as button. So a new Link will be forced. That automaticly runs a reload if you have no href set. This is because in the sample a simple `<span>` element is used as button.

i hope this will be helpfully to you.

And another thing. I'm very sure there are tons of questions for dropdown menus in the database. Try to find samples to fix your code.

Another trick can be to do the dropdown only with css but i think this will be to hard for the beginning. ohterwise use your favorite search engine on look for "css only dropdown"

Comment: Thanks! That was helpfuly for me.